# Convert integer to formatted LPCWSTR. C++

Tags: c++

I have a direct3d project that uses D3DXCreateTextureFromFile() to load some images.  This function takes a LPCWSTR for the path to file.  I want to load a series of textures that are numbered consecutively (ie. MyImage0001.jpg, MyImage0002.jpg, etc)  But c++'s crazy strings confuse me.

How do i:

```
for(int i=0; i < 3;i++)
{
//How do I convert i into a string path i can use with D3DXCreateTextureFromFile?
}
```

Edit:

I should mention I am using Visual Studio 2008's compiler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is [`std::swprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf):

```
wchar_t buffer[256];
std::swprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(*buffer),
              L"MyImage%04d.jpg", i);
```

You could also use a [`std::wstringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_wstringstream):

```
std::wstringstream ws;
ws << L"MyImage" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill(L'0') << i << L".jpg";
ws.str().c_str();  // get the underlying text array
```

Answer (score 3):

The most 'C++' way would be to use [wstringstream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e8f34fb(VS.80).aspx):

```
#include <sstream>

//...

std::wstringstream ss;
ss << 3;
LPCWSTR str = ss.str().c_str();
```

Comment: For stringstream's you need to do `ss.str().c_str();`

Answer (score 1):

The Win32 API has multiple string formatting functions available, eg:

[wsprintf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx):

```
WCHAR buffer[SomeMaxLengthHere];
for(int i=0; i < 3;i++)
{
    wsprintfW(buffer, L"%i", i);
    ...
}
```

[StringCbPrintf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647510.aspx):

```
WCHAR buffer[SomeMaxLengthHere];
for(int i=0; i < 3;i++)
{
    StringCbPrintfW(buffer, sizeof(buffer), L"%i", I);
    ...
}
```

[StringCchPrintf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647541.aspx):

```
WCHAR buffer[SomeMaxLengthHere];
for(int i=0; i < 3;i++)
{
    StringCchPrintfW(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(WCHAR), L"%i", i);
    ...
}
```

Just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

wsprintf

```
/* wsprintf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  wchar_t buffer [50];
  for(int i=0; i < 3;i++){
     wsprintf (buffer, L"File%d.jpg", i);
     // buffer now contains the file1.jpg, then file2.jpg etc
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't produce wide strings, but the idea was ok and can be converted to `wsprintf`.